# Connect OpenVPN with a config file behind http/https proxy

Tags: vpn, proxy, openvpn

I would like to connect to a VPN using OpenVPN from the terminal 
openvpn --config client.ovpn 
, but I have to connect behind a http/https proxy for accessing internet.  So, how do I set it ? 
Likewise, if I decide to connect using this https://nordvpn.com/tutorials/linux/pptp/ , how to set it behind a proxy ? 
I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Edit:

I managed to connect to the vpn by editing the ovpn file. But, I don't think it's working fine. Here are the logs.

```
Sat Aug 22 20:23:44 2015 WARNING: --ping should normally be used with --ping-restart or --ping-exit
Sat Aug 22 20:23:44 2015 NOTE: --fast-io is disabled since we are not using UDP
Sat Aug 22 20:23:44 2015 Control Channel Authentication: tls-auth using INLINE static key file
Sat Aug 22 20:23:44 2015 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Sat Aug 22 20:23:44 2015 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Sat Aug 22 20:23:44 2015 Socket Buffers: R=[87380->131072] S=[16384->131072]
Sat Aug 22 20:23:44 2015 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]10.3.100.207:8080 [nonblock]
Sat Aug 22 20:23:45 2015 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]10.3.100.207:8080
Sat Aug 22 20:23:45 2015 Send to HTTP proxy: 'CONNECT 158.255.212.117:443 HTTP/1.0'
Sat Aug 22 20:23:46 2015 HTTP proxy returned: 'HTTP/1.1 200 Connection Established'
Sat Aug 22 20:23:48 2015 TCPv4_CLIENT link local: [undef]
Sat Aug 22 20:23:48 2015 TCPv4_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]10.3.100.207:8080
Sat Aug 22 20:23:48 2015 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]10.3.100.207:8080, sid=517792d2 be30e636
Sat Aug 22 20:23:48 2015 WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
Sat Aug 22 20:23:51 2015 VERIFY OK: depth=1, C=AT, ST=AT, L=SanFrancisco, O=NordVPN, OU=AT, CN=vpn-at.nordvpn.com, name=vpn-at.nordvpn.com, emailAddress=mail@host.domain
Sat Aug 22 20:23:51 2015 Validating certificate key usage
Sat Aug 22 20:23:51 2015 ++ Certificate has key usage  00a0, expects 00a0
Sat Aug 22 20:23:51 2015 VERIFY KU OK
Sat Aug 22 20:23:51 2015 Validating certificate extended key usage
Sat Aug 22 20:23:51 2015 ++ Certificate has EKU (str) TLS Web Server Authentication, expects TLS Web Server Authentication
Sat Aug 22 20:23:51 2015 VERIFY EKU OK
Sat Aug 22 20:23:51 2015 VERIFY OK: depth=0, C=PA, ST=PA, L=Panama, O=NordVPN, OU=NordVPN, CN=vpn-at.nordvpn.com, name=NordVPN, emailAddress=cert@nordvpn.com
Sat Aug 22 20:23:55 2015 Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'AES-256-CBC' initialized with 256 bit key
Sat Aug 22 20:23:55 2015 Data Channel Encrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Sat Aug 22 20:23:55 2015 Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'AES-256-CBC' initialized with 256 bit key
Sat Aug 22 20:23:55 2015 Data Channel Decrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Sat Aug 22 20:23:55 2015 Control Channel: TLSv1, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, 2048 bit RSA
Sat Aug 22 20:23:55 2015 [vpn-at.nordvpn.com] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]10.3.100.207:8080
Sat Aug 22 20:23:57 2015 SENT CONTROL [vpn-at.nordvpn.com]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
Sat Aug 22 20:23:57 2015 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,redirect-gateway def1,dhcp-option DNS 198.7.63.141,dhcp-option DNS 78.46.223.24,route 10.7.7.1,topology net30,ping 5,ping-restart 30,ifconfig 10.7.7.202 10.7.7.201'
Sat Aug 22 20:23:57 2015 OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modified
Sat Aug 22 20:23:57 2015 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
Sat Aug 22 20:23:57 2015 OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
Sat Aug 22 20:23:57 2015 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ip-win32 and/or --dhcp-option options modified
Sat Aug 22 20:23:57 2015 ROUTE_GATEWAY 10.109.66.2/255.255.255.0 IFACE=eth0 HWADDR=d4:be:d9:4b:85:fc
Sat Aug 22 20:23:57 2015 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Sat Aug 22 20:23:57 2015 TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
Sat Aug 22 20:23:57 2015 do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=0, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Sat Aug 22 20:23:57 2015 /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
Sat Aug 22 20:23:57 2015 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 local 10.7.7.202 peer 10.7.7.201
Sat Aug 22 20:23:57 2015 /sbin/ip route add 10.3.100.207/32 via 10.109.66.2
Sat Aug 22 20:23:57 2015 /sbin/ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 via 10.7.7.201
Sat Aug 22 20:23:57 2015 /sbin/ip route add 128.0.0.0/1 via 10.7.7.201
Sat Aug 22 20:23:57 2015 /sbin/ip route add 10.7.7.1/32 via 10.7.7.201
Sat Aug 22 20:23:57 2015 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

But, nothing new seems to happen with the internet i.e. same functionality as before.

Answer (score 3):

Edit your `.ovpn` file and put your tcp connection line under connection tag and define all needy_proxy there.

```
<connection>
remote vpn_ip_here vpn_port tcp
http-proxy y.y.y.y 8080 (replaced actual IP here)
http-proxy-retry
</connection>
```

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...

Comment: Fabby is it all right now ??

Comment: Now it is!  **:P**  After the edit(http://askubuntu.com/users/344926/fabby) it was good enough to receive an upvote from me (For the record: I wasn't the one downvoting) **Keep up the good work!  :-)**

Answer (score 0):

when we use openvpn via one proxy we can use this command:

http-proxy PROXY-IP PROXY-PORT auto

USERNAME

PASSWORD

if we need to connect two or more proxies in a row with a separate username and password, this command should be changed. For example, after connecting to the first proxy, connect to the next proxy server respectively and then establish a connection with the main VPN server. can you help me about this new command? thx.

thank you.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1208098)